# Challenging Circle Theorem

Tags: geometry, circles

In the given figure $PQRS$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. $PQ$ and $SR$ are produced up to center $O$ of the circle. $OT$ and $OR$ are the radii of the circle. $QR$ and $PS$ are produced upto the point $V$ and $PV$ and $TR$ are produced up to the point $U$. Prove that: $RV=UV$.

[image]

My attempt:

Given: $PQRS$ is a cyclic quadrilateral

To Prove: $RV=UV$

Proof

1. $$\angle PSR =\angle URS+\angle SUR$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\triangle{OTR}$ is an isosceles triangle with $OT=OR$, 
$$\angle{OTR}=\angle{ORT}=\angle{ORQ}+\angle{QRT},$$
i.e.
$$\angle{URV}=\angle{QRT}=\angle{OTR}-\angle{ORQ}\tag1$$

Also, using $\angle{QPS}=\angle{ORQ}$,
$$\begin{align}\angle{RUV}&=\angle{OTR}-\angle{QPS}\\&=\angle{OTR}-\angle{ORQ}\end{align}\tag2$$

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $\angle{URV}=\angle{RUV}$.